# Анимация поднятия блока на css3?

Tags: css, css3, html5

Как реализовать css анимацию когда пользователь кликнул на input, тоесть когда он активный
Поднять плавно input к верху на 100px. Реализовать на css3

Answer (score 2):

```css
input {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.4s;
}

input:focus {
  top: -100px;
}
```

```html
Some text...
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<input type="text">
```